# i18next translation file management

Tags: json, internationalization, i18next

I am working on a project that is using i18next for localisation and translations.

Currently the translation directory is made up of a load of .json files for each language like so:

```
locales
  - en.json
  - de.json
  - fr.json
  - index.js
  - i18n.js
```

Where each file is of the structure:

```
{
  "translation": {
    "navbar": {
      "logo": "English Logo",
      "localeSwitcher": "Language",
      "currencySwitcher": "Currency"
    },
    "breadcrumbs": {
      "home": "Homepage"
    }
  }
}
```

And each file is then imported in `index.js`:

```
import en from './en.json';
import de from './de.json';
import es from './es.json';
import pt from './pt.json';
import nl from './nl.json';
import fr from './fr.json';
import ru from './ru.json';
import zh from './zh.json';

const locales = {
  en,
  de,
  pt,
  es,
  nl,
  fr,
  ru,
  zh
};

export default locales;
```

I'd like to find a way to manage these translation files as each time I add a translation I have to manually add the same key in the right place in each file and I have no way of verifying that each translation file includes all the translations found in the master file, en.json.

I have done some searching and am unable to find any system for handling these files in a more intelligent manner than just manually updating each one. Does anyone have a suggestion of doing this in a more systematic and structured way?

Comment: have a look at http://locize.com - comes from the makers of i18next